# F0 drawing in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for a way to do this in LaTeX. I want to have the F0 of the sentence over the sentence or at the bottom of the sentence as shown in the attached picture.
[image]
Thanks indeed
Muhamamd

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! This is surely possible using TikZ. How's that curve generated --- a specific formula, or is it just the general shape that's important?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is fairly simple to do using package `tikz` and the `tikzmark` library. There are lots of parameters here that you can fiddle with to get exactly what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \{\tikzmarknode{A}{W}ould you like some c\tikzmarknode{B}{o}\tikzmarknode{C}{ff}e\tikzmarknode{D}{e}\}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \coordinate (point 1) at ($(A.north) + (0, 0.2)$);
        \coordinate (point 2) at ($(B.north) + (0, 0.6)$);
        \coordinate (point 3) at ($(C.north) + (0.05, 0.3)$);
        \coordinate (point 4) at ($(D.north) + (0, 0.6)$);
        \draw[fill=black] (point 1) circle[radius=0.075cm];
        \draw[fill=black] (point 2) circle[radius=0.075cm];
        \draw[fill=black] (point 3) circle[radius=0.075cm];
        \draw[fill=black] (point 4) circle[radius=0.075cm];
        \draw (point 1) -- ($(point 1) + (2, 0)$) to[out=0, in=-135] (point 2);
        \draw (point 2) to[out=-60, in=150] (point 3);
        \draw (point 3) to[out=30, in=-120] (point 4);
        \draw ($(B.south) + (0, -0.1)$) -- ($(B.south) - (0, 0.5)$);
        \node[below right] at ($(B.south) - (0.15, 0.5)$) {H\(^*\)LH\%};
        \node[below] at ($(A.south) - (0, 0.5)$) {\%L};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```